# does pyinstaller support zeep?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, zeep

My environment:
python 3.8,
zeep 4.0,
pyinstaller 4.1

When i used pyinstaller to transfer name.exe, it's successful
but it's not work

and this is my code:

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.cache import SqliteCache
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from urllib3 import disable_warnings
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import osenter



disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
username = 'test'
password = 'test'
host = '192.168.200.201'
wsdl = 'AXLAPI.wsdl'
location = 'https://{host}:8443/axl/'.format(host=host)
binding = "{http://www.cisco.com/AXLAPIService/}AXLAPIBinding"
session = Session()
session.verify = False
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
transport = Transport(cache=SqliteCache(), session=session, timeout=20)
history = HistoryPlugin()
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=transport, plugins=[history])
service = client.create_service(binding, location)
os.system("pause")
try:
    partition_resp = service.listPhone(
        searchCriteria={'name': 'CSF571130'}, returnedTags={'name': '', 'userLocale': '', 'phoneTemplateName': '', 'singleButtonBarge': '', 'numberOfButtons': '', 'model': '', 'product': '', 'ownerUserName': '', 'class': '', 'commonPhoneConfigName': '', 'securityProfileName': '', 'sipProfileName': '', 'softkeyTemplateName': '', 'devicePoolName': '', 'locationName': '', 'builtInBridgeStatus': '', 'useTrustedRelayPoint': '', 'certificateOperation': '', 'deviceMobilityMode': '', 'protocol': '', 'protocolSide': ''})
    print(partition_resp)
except:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Pyinstaller is not supporting Python 3.8. I know that people wanted to add support but I don't know if they succeeded and / or it was released. So I think this might be the reason why it is not working for you.

Comment: thanks your reply,but pyinstaller 4.1 add support python3.8

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/CHANGES.html#id1